# Windows Authentication in ASP .Net for WebApi

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, tfs, asp.net-web-api

I have written a simple ASP.Net WebAPI that download a file from an on-prem tfs server using a rest call. The issue is when I connect to this site from my user account(corp domain), and set the credentials in webRequest to CredentialsCache.DefaultCredentials, it works fine since I am a vlid user on the tfs project.
Now someone else in my team wishes to use the same webAPI and when they hit the same url, I could see that its my credentials being used again to download the file.
I suspect this is because of using CredentialsCache.DefaultCredentials in my controller code, but I am not able to find a way using which I should be able to use the client's identity to be used for the download request.
My question is , is there a way to extract the windows identity or network credentials of the remote user(on the same domain) which I can use for Authentication. I am sorry if this is a DUP but I could not find a targetted answer to my question yet. Sample code is pasted below.

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);

        request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;

        try
        {
            var webResponse = request.GetResponse();
            var webStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream();
            if (webStream != null)
            {
                var objReader = new StreamReader(webStream);
                return objReader.ReadToEnd()
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if I understand you correctly but I think impersonation is what you're looking for:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xh507fc5.ASPX